# Why does SciPy ttest_rel return numpy ndarray of NaN?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I am trying to calculate t-test score of data stored in different dataframes using `ttest_rel` from `scipy.stats`. But when calculating t-test between same data, it is returning a numpy ndarray of NaN instead of a single NaN. What am I doing wrong that I am getting a numpy array instead of a single value?

My code with a sample dataframe is as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
from scipy.stats import ttest_rel

cities_nhl = pd.DataFrame({'metro': ['NewYork', 'LosAngeles', 'StLouis', 'Detroit', 'Boston', 'Baltimore'],
                           'total_ratio': [0.45, 0.51, 0.62, 0.43, 0.26, 0.32]})
cities_nba = pd.DataFrame({'metro': ['Boston', 'LosAngeles', 'Phoenix', 'Baltimore', 'Detroit', 'NewYork'],
                           'total_ratio': [0.50, 0.41, 0.34, 0.53, 0.33, 0.42]})
cities_mlb = pd.DataFrame({'metro': ['Seattle', 'Detroit', 'Boston', 'Baltimore', 'NewYork', 'LosAngeles'],
                           'total_ratio': [0.48, 0.27, 0.52, 0.33, 0.28, 0.67]})
cities_nfl = pd.DataFrame({'metro': ['LosAngeles', 'Atlanta', 'Detroit', 'Boston', 'NewYork', 'Baltimore'],
                           'total_ratio': [0.47, 0.41, 0.82, 0.13, 0.56, 0.42]})

needed_cols = ['metro', 'total_ratio'] #metro is a string and total_ratio is a float column
df_dict = {'NHL': cities_nhl[needed_cols], 'NBA': cities_nba[needed_cols],
           'MLB': cities_mlb[needed_cols], 'NFL': cities_nfl[needed_cols]} #keeping all dataframes in a dictionary  
                                                                           #for ease of access
sports = ['NHL','NBA','MLB','NFL'] #name of sports
p_values_dict = {'NHL':[], 'NBA':[], 'MLB':[], 'NFL':[]} #dictionary to store p values
for clm1 in sports:
    for clm2 in sports:
        #merge the dataframes of two sports and then calculate their ttest score
        _df = pd.merge(df_dict[clm1], df_dict[clm2], 
                          how='inner', on='metro', suffixes=[f'_{clm1}', f'_{clm2}'])
        _pval = ttest_rel(_df[f"total_ratio_{clm1}"], _df[f"total_ratio_{clm2}"])[1]
        p_values_dict[clm1].append(_pval)
p_values = pd.DataFrame(p_values_dict, index=sports)
p_values
```

```
|       |NHL        |NBA        |MLB        |NFL       |
|-------|-----------|-----------|-----------|----------|
|NHL    |[nan, nan] |0.589606   |0.826298   |0.38493   |
|NBA    |0.589606   |[nan, nan] |0.779387   |0.782173  |
|MLB    |0.826298   |0.779387   |[nan, nan] |0.713229  |
|NFL    |0.38493    |0.782173   |0.713229   |[nan, nan]|
```

Comment: `scipy.stats.ttest_rel` returns a tuple of two values: the t-statistic and the p-value. see the docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html

Comment: @jkr Yes. Here I am using only the p-value. On the 4th last line (`_pval = ttest_rel(_df[f"total_ratio_{clm1}"], _df[f"total_ratio_{clm2}"])[1]`), I take the 2nd item of the tuple.

Comment: the 2 distributions are the same, so what output were you expecting to get?

Comment: @chitown88 I am getting `[nan, nan]` which is a numpy array. Shouldn't I get a single `NaN`?

Comment: Ya I'm not sure why you get the 2. I tried looking into it, maybe when it has a NaN, it goes into checking each tail?? No idea. Good question to maybe ask scipy developers directly. Like I said I couldn't find anything in the documentation

Comment: Thank you @chitown88. I will try to contact the developers.

Comment: @Imran, if you find out, be sure to post as a solution here.

Comment: @chitown88 Of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is actually not related to `scipy`, but is due to duplicate column labels in your dataframes. In this part of your code:

```
        _df = pd.merge(df_dict[clm1], df_dict[clm2], 
                          how='inner', on='metro', suffixes=[f'_{clm1}', f'_{clm2}'])
```

When `clm1` and `clm2` are equal (say they are both `NHL`), you get a `_df` dataframe like this:

```
        metro  total_ratio_NHL  total_ratio_NHL
0     NewYork             0.45             0.45
1  LosAngeles             0.51             0.51
2     StLouis             0.62             0.62
3     Detroit             0.43             0.43
4      Boston             0.26             0.26
5   Baltimore             0.32             0.32
```

Then, when you pass the columns to the `ttest_rel` function, you end up passing both columns when you refer to a single column label, because they have the same label:

```
ttest_rel(_df[f"total_ratio_{clm1}"], _df[f"total_ratio_{clm2}"])
```

And that's how you get two t-statistics and two p-values.

So, you can modify those two lines to eliminate duplicate column labels, like this:

```
        _df = pd.merge(df_dict[clm1], df_dict[clm2], 
                          how='inner', on='metro', suffixes=[f'_{clm1}_1', f'_{clm2}_2'])
        _pval = ttest_rel(_df[f"total_ratio_{clm1}_1"], _df[f"total_ratio_{clm2}_2"])[1]
```

The result will look like this:

```
         NHL         NBA         MLB         NFL
NHL      NaN    0.589606    0.826298    0.384930
NBA 0.589606         NaN    0.779387    0.782173
MLB 0.826298    0.779387         NaN    0.713229
NFL 0.384930    0.782173    0.713229         NaN
```

Comment: I assumed that the problem was because I messed up something but I couldn't find it myself. Thank you.